# Why are there 2 ways to Validate in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

You can use `Model Validation Rules` and `FormRequest/Request Validaiton Rules`.

So there are Scenarios:

- Form
- Rest Create

Should you use a `Model Validation` regardless?
Why are there 2 methods?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provides a powerful Validation class that you can benefit from by using several approaches.
So, you can validate inside the model, and this works best if you need to centralize the logic at the model during creation or update. Also it works if you create Intermediate Models, or creating Models offline, for example Model to hold Reports.

Form Requests is a special way to handle Validation, you can handle the validation inside the Controller, or you can go slim Controllers, and move the Validation elsewhere. Form Requests is better when you are handling complex validation, or if you are using the same validation through different Controllers.

So the Validation class is the same, how you make use of it is up to you.

Comment: So whether web request or from a Web Form it will still validate using the specified `FormRequest`?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I am following here. What is the difference here? A Web form is submitted through a web request.